Two crowns, one corresponding to na'aseh, one to nishmah?
B"H
It says in the Gemara (Shabbat 88a) that when the people of Yisroel said "we will do" (na'aseh) before "we will listen" (nishmah), 600,000 angels came and tied two crowns to each of their heads; one corresponding to "we will do" and one corresponding to "we will listen".
The fact that it says that there are only two, one for the very fact that they said "we will do" and one just because they said "we will listen", then what did they get as a reward for saying "we will do" before we will listen?
Seemingly even if they would have said "we will listen" first, they would still have received two crowns.
So what did they get for prefacing "we will do"? Would they still have gotten two crowns even if they didn't?

You know you can answer your own questions.

@shmosel if I knew the answer I could. Why mention that fact in this case?

It's a classic question in chassidus. Did you just happen to think it up?

@shmosel I've heard of the question in chassidus, but I don't remember the answer

The Rebbe Maharash explains that נשמע following נעשה corresponds to the שוב following רצוא, which can only be achieved in the proper sequence. So while they are distinct stages with separate "crowns," it's only possible to attain the pair by virtue of הקדמת נעשה לנשמע.

This question is asked and answered in the maamar בשעה שהקדימו תשי״ב.

אמנם עפ"ז צריך להבין, דכיון שגדלה מעלת הקדמת נעשה לנשמע שעל ידה היתה
נתינת הכתרים בשביל נעשה ונשמע, הי' צריך להיות נתינת כתר גם בשביל
ההקדמה עצמה
However, based on this, one must understand: Since the greatness of
the precedence of "we will do" to "we will hear" is what caused the
giving of crowns for "we will do" and "we will hear," there should
have been a crown given for the precedence itself.

In it, he informs us that indeed, there is a third crown to represent the precedence of Na'aseh over Nishma, but it is not given to Benei Yisrael per se, but given to Hashem. After giving the perush1 of R'zl on קדושים יט, ב, which discusses a mashal of a king being given 3 crowns by his subjects, he says:

מזה מובן גם
בנוגע להכתרים שבמתן תורה, ששני הכתרים שכנגד נעשה וכנגד נשמע הם הכתרים
שנתן בראש בניו, ונוסף לזה ישנו גם כתר הג' שע"י עבודת ההקדמה דנעשה
לנשמע, אלא שכתר זה נטל לעצמו
From this, it is understood regarding the
crowns given at the giving of the Torah, that the two crowns
corresponding to "we will do" and "we will hear" are the crowns placed
on the heads of His children, and in addition to this, there is a third
crown, which is due to the service of the precedence of "we will do"
to "we will hear" which He took for Himself.


The explanation for why this is, is very deep and involved and makes up the rest of the maamar, but to keep it simple:
The precedence of "we will do" over "we will hear" implies something very great. It implies that it is not only His Will that we accept; it is Him, Himself, that we accept - the One Who Wills.
His ultimate Will (which goes above and is the source of the desires to benefit creations2, to be known3, to be complete in action as well as potential4), i.e. His Root Desire, is to have a dwelling place in the lowest world, as is well known to those who study Chassidus. What is less well known, however, is that there is a root, even of this "root" Desire.

שזהו מה שנתאווה הקב"ה להיות לו ית' דירה בתחתונים,... הם בבחירה דוקא, וכן הוא גם ברצון
המוחלט, והחלטת הרצון היא ע"י נשמות ישראל דוקא, להיותם מושרשים למעלה
מבחי' הרצון – בבחי' בעל הרצון.
God's desire to have a dwelling place in the lower worlds... these are
matters of free will, and so is the even this root desire. The
root of the root desire is by the souls of Israel specifically, as they are rooted above the level of desire, i.e. in the level of the
One Who Wills.

To put it simply, if we say that His Desire is to get married and make a dwelling with Israel, it was Israel herself who gave Him this Desire, when He "saw her" for the first time5, so to speak. Or to put it romantically:

"I never wanted to get married, and then I met you..."6

This means that Israel, His Beloved, is rooted right in His Very Self - the One Who Wills, Himself. The souls of Israel are rooted in His Essence on this level. Therefore, by accepting Him, not just His Will, the crown goes to Him (or, he says, you could say it goes to us, who are One with Him, Himself, through our own free choice and acceptance).
Us marrying Him, Himself, truly, at Sinai is His crowning achievement, and our great fortune!

1. ויק"ר פכ"ד, ח. וראה גם מאמרי אדה"ז תקס"ב ח"א ע׳ שח. רד"ה צאינה וראינה תר"ס. תרח"ץ. תש"ח. ועוד
2. דרך׳ ה
3. זוהר
4. עץ חיים
5. אלא מהבחי' שבה נאמר ואוהב את יעקב דוקא, שזהו כפי שנה"א מושרשת בהעצמות, כמאמר במי נמלך בנשמותיהן (ויש גירסא בנפשותיהן) של צדיקים, דענין ההמלכה הוא במדריגה שלמעלה מהרצון
6. ז׳) שהעבודה היא צורך גבוה 

There are many shiurim on the topic of "the two crowns." I think that this one provides a good answer to the question posed by @Awtsmoos:
The Secret of the Two Crown by Rabbi Daniel Z Feldman
https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/711569/The-Secret-of-the-Two-Crowns
"The Talmud relates that the exclamation of the Jews, “Na’aseh V’Nishma”, was so impressive to the Angels that they responded by crowning the Jews with two crowns each, one for Na’aseh and one for Nishma. However, it requires some explanation as to why this inverted order, implying a commitment without being informed of the details, is so laudatory; and presuming that it is, one crown would appear sufficient, rather than two.
"In explanation, the Beit HaLevi (in the introduction to his Responsa; in I, 6 of those Responsa; and in his commentary al haTorah) suggests that Na’aseh actually contains Nishma within it, as it would be impossible to perform the mitzvot without first learning their details. The greatness of stating Nishma after Na’aseh was that it indicated an acceptance of Torah study above and beyond that which was necessary to fufill the mitzvot. Thus, the phrase, which actually means “Nishma V’Na’aseh V’Nishma”, conveys two separate acceptances of the study of Torah: that which is practically necessary for observing the halakhah; and beyond that, study in and of itself, separate from any practical considerations. Hence, two crowns are appropriate: inverting the order of the words turned one acceptance into two. (The Bet HaLevi’s great-grandson, Rav Joseph B. Soloveichik, suggested a different explanation of the greatness of “Na’aseh V’Nishma”; see “Reflections of the Rav”.)"
The Crowns of Torah by Rabbi Yirmiyahu Ullman at https://ohr.edu/4159   includes this passage:
"The Talmud (Shabbat 88a) asserts that when the Jews unconditionally agreed to accept the Torah, preceding their commitment to observe before hearing the reasons and explanations for the commandments, G-d exclaimed, “Who revealed this secret to them, which only the ministering angels know?” And in the merit of this two-phrased, unconditional commitment, 600,000 angels descended from Heaven and conferred two crowns on the head of each Jew – one on account of “we shall observe” and one on account of “we shall hear”."
"Of course, these were not literal crowns, but special “spheres” of influence that enlightened their minds and enabled them to perceive the depths of the Torah."

I think you're missing the question. The implication is that they were rewarded for prefacing naaseh to nishmah, but the fact that they were given two crowns suggests that they were rewarded for each individually, not for the relationship between them.

Many people want to get an extra crown for saying we will do, but the package was 2 crowns for saying the right sequence. Kindergarden! Just like all people learn, saying "we will do" opened their minds to say "we will do and we will listen".
